# building a docker container stuck on timezone

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

Building a container with Ubuntu 20.04, and got asked to chose the timezone. In my dockerfile I set  it to be noninteractive, but it still is asking me for it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ENV TZ=US \     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

`=> [stage-1 21/28] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y nvidia-driver-470                              529.9s  => => #   1. Africa        6. Asia            11. System V timezones                                                   => => #   2. America       7. Atlantic Ocean  12. US                                                                   => => #   3. Antarctica    8. Europe          13. None of the above                                                    => => #   4. Australia     9. Indian Ocean                                                                             => => #   5. Arctic Ocean  10. Pacific Ocean                                                                           => => # Geographic area:`

Tried: `ENV TZ=US \     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

Here is a part of my Dockerfile

```
FROM freesurfer/freesurfer:7.1.1 as Stage1

ENV TZ=US \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Stage 2
FROM deepmi/fastsurfer:gpu-v2.1.1

# Dev install. git for pip editable install.
RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y nvidia-driver-440 && \
    apt-get install -y wget &&  \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y apt-utils git && \
    apt-get -y install curl && \
    apt-get install libgomp1 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Comment: Please show us the *complete* Dockerfile (or least something sufficient for us to reproduce this behavior).

Comment: added it in the edit.

Comment: Env is for a single env var

Comment: @DanielA.White that is incorrect; see [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env), which clearly shows how to set multiple environment variables with a single `ENV` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a multi-stage build. You're only setting the environment in the first stage. At least in your example, you're not actually using *anything* in the first stage, so you could simplify your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM deepmi/fastsurfer:gpu-v2.1.1

ENV TZ=US \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Dev install. git for pip editable install.
RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y nvidia-driver-440 && \
    apt-get install -y wget &&  \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y apt-utils git && \
    apt-get -y install curl && \
    apt-get install libgomp1 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

If you actually need multiple build stages, you'll need to add the `ENV` directive to each stage:

```
FROM freesurfer/freesurfer:7.1.1 as Stage1

ENV TZ=US \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
.
.
.

# Stage 2
FROM deepmi/fastsurfer:gpu-v2.1.1

ENV TZ=US \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
.
.
.
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but running multiple `apt-get install` statements is suboptimal, because that means `apt-get` has to re-calculate dependencies multiple times. Just install everything at once:

```
FROM deepmi/fastsurfer:gpu-v2.1.1

ENV TZ=US \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Dev install. git for pip editable install.
RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y \
      nvidia-driver-440 \
      wget \
      curl \
      libgomp1 && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
      apt-utils \
      git && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Here we still have two `apt-get install` command because you're applying `--no-install-recommends` to a couple packages. Otherwise I would bundle everything into a single command.

Comment: Thanks that worked- setting the environment for both stages